# how to open links on same page/frame in php?

Tags: php

I would like to open this page on the same index page 
How can I put this link in the index page?

```
<a herf="includes/user_manage.php?id =<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
<a herf ="index.php?page=includes/user_manage.php?id =<?php echo $id; ?> ">
```

But it works if I use:

```
<a herf="includes/user_manage.php?id =<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: it's `href` by the way

Comment: No it doesn't work. You should write `href` instead of `herf`

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: `herf` actually works even without missing `Link Text</a>`?! wow, that's news to me * grin *

Comment: @Aody Please edit your question/code.

Comment: To maybe answer your question and if this is related to `iframe`, as you mention `page/frame` in your question's title; to open a page in the same place, you'd need to use `parent`. I.e. `target="_parent"`, something to that affect. Google it, you'll find different options such as JS.

Answer (score 2):

You have a type error

try

```
<a href="includes/user_manage.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> Link </a>
```

To help you remember that you can pick any one of these that will stick in your head

```
Hypermedia Reference
Hypertext Reference
HTTP Reference
Hyperlink Reference
HTML Reference
```

Seeing as i have no idea what `href` stands for. it can be whatever you wan't it to be

Comment: I believe you meant: "Seeing as i have no idea what `herf` stands for. it can be whatever you wan't it to be" ;)

Comment: Actually no, so that was a fail... LMAO do you know what `href` stands for?

Comment: I'll take an educated guess LOL! "hypertext reference"? I stand at being wrong here, I know. lol Do tell...

Comment: Ok, I got the gist of your answer now hahaha! I thought you were making reference to the OP's `herf`, that's why I said that. I have a tendancy to pull more towards `hypertext reference`, seeing that's what a link is called, from what I've learned over the years.

Comment: LMAO..... well that's good then

Comment: Good, is.... good! :) cheers